# Page loaded over HTTPS but requested an insecure. I cannot find it

Tags: javascript, wordpress, https

I've got a https://billage.es/blog wordpress site and everything works fine. 
However when I scroll down the page and it goes to fetch more posts the console is complaining showing me the following message:
The page at 'https://www.billage.es/blog/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image.

The thing is that I've already corrected some other messages like this however I cannot find this one: billag-blanc.png file.

Any help on this will be appreciate.

best regards,

Pau Pujol

Comment: probably, the image you are loading does not have a secure url. What do you mean, "you cannot find it"

Comment: I meant that when I checked the html code on the browser I couldn't find the html code causing the error, that is: http://billage.es/blog..../billage-blanc.png. Therefore I wasn't able to remove it from my sources. Thank you for your interest!

Answer (score 1):

You are loading the image "billage-blanc.png" on HTTP but you are just not seeing it on the screen, take a look at the image attached, change that in your code and you can eradicate the warning thrown by the browser.

[image: Markup screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I've solved. However, could you explain me plesase how have you found it? Cause if a inspect the code on a browser the console raise the error however I wasn't able to find it.! Again, thank you.

Comment: Even for me it was a bit hard becuase it was dynamically added to the DOM on scroll, I just copied the html under the page-content div from chrome dev console after scrolling down, put it in a text editor and did a search, the chrome dev console based search did not work for some reason.

Comment: Thank you Pradeep!